# Why is my function in NDSolve not equivalent to "If"?[update 1]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, user-defined-functions, differential-equations

My questioin is: why `rhsexpr` works but `rhsfunc` doesn't. Thanks. :)

```
    m = l = 1.; \[Mu] = 100;
    beltv[t_] = .1;
    spring[x_] = 1000. (l - x);

    viscous[v_] := -30. (v - beltv[t]);
    coulomb[v_] := -25. Sign[v - beltv[t]];
    stribeck[v_] := -.3 Sign[v] Exp[-2 Abs[v]];

    friction[v_] := viscous[v] + coulomb[v] + stribeck[v];
```

`rhsfunc` is defined as:

```
    rhsfunc[t_, x_, 1] := beltv'[t];
    rhsfunc[t_, x_, 0] := spring[x[t]] + friction[x'[t]];
```

`rhsexpr` is defined as:

```
    rhsexpr := 
      If[stuck[t] == 1, beltv'[t], spring[x[t]] + friction[x'[t]]];
```

`rhsexpr` works.

```
     NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == rhsexpr , x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[x'[t] == beltv[t] && spring[x[t]]^2 <  \[Mu]^2, stuck[t] -> 1], 
      WhenEvent[spring[x[t]]^2 >=  \[Mu]^2, stuck[t] -> 0], 
      stuck[0] == 0}, {x[t], x'[t]}, {t, 0, 2}, 
     DiscreteVariables -> stuck[t]]
```

`rhsfunc` doesn't work, prompting that Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0

```
    NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == rhsfunc[t, x[t], stuck[t]] , x[0] == 1, 
      x'[0] == 0, 
      WhenEvent[x'[t] == beltv[t] && spring[x[t]]^2 <  \[Mu]^2, 
       stuck[t] -> 1], 
      WhenEvent[spring[x[t]]^2 >=  \[Mu]^2, stuck[t] -> 0], stuck[0] == 0}, {x[t], x'[t]}, {t, 0, 2},  DiscreteVariables -> stuck[t]]
```

[image]

**update 1**

Actually, I defines the `rhsfunc` just as the m@ does as in  its bulit-in documentalion which is showed below:

```
rhs[t_, x_, 1] = -x;
rhs[t_, x_, 2] = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == rhs[t, x[t], a[t]], x[0] == 1, a[0] == 1, 
WhenEvent[x[t] - .1, a[t] -> 2], 
WhenEvent[x[t] - 2, a[t] -> 1]}, {x, a}, {t, 0, 15}, 
DiscreteVariables -> {a[t] \[Element] {1, 2}}];

Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `rhsfunc[t_?NumberQ, x_?NumberQ,1]:= ...`

Comment: Thanks Matariki. I tried it, but it doesn't work, still prompting "non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0".

Comment: be sure to clear your old def...

Comment: I am sure that I cleared everthing before I modify then run according to matariki's suggestion. I even quit the kernel before I run the modified code. Please see my attached screenshot. It just doesn't work. Anyway, thanks george.

Comment: try rhsfunc[t_, x_, __] for the second case (instead of explicit 0). that is actually what your rhsexpr does. I'm guessing on first pass ndsolve tries a symbolic value for stuck[] which is undefined as you have it.

Comment: I don't thinks this is the problem, please see my update. The third argument was used to swich the right hand side of the equation. I just mimic what M@ dose as in its buil-in example. So why can the built-in example run correctly, but mine doesn't. Thanks george.

Comment: sorry no answer, but a few more comments. First your rhsexpr version you say works just crashes mathematica 9 (hard kernel crash no error message).  I guess the solution is running away unstable. Your event condition exact equality (xprime==beltv) is unlikely to ever occur in a numerical simulation.  I suspect your discretevariable should also appear in the variables list ie {x,xptime,stuck}.  The docs for ndsolvevalue dont give any example though..

Comment: also I'd sugest you take this over to mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: M@ V9.0.0 has a bug that it even can't run its own built-in example code:`{sol, points} = Reap@NDSolve[{x'[t] == -y[t] - x[t]^2, y'[t] == 2 x[t] - y[t]^3, x[0] == y[0] == 1, WhenEvent[y[t] == 0 && x[t] > 0, Sow[{x[t], y[t]}]]}, {x, y}, {t, 14}]`. V9.0.1 corrects this. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: By the way, if you replace "&&" in the above code in my comment with "And", then V9.0.0 can run correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patterns are not much like If statement, especially in your example, where the If ststement is delayed.
Patterns require an exact agreement with the definitions, and since you didn't define what happens for rhsfunc when it gets non numerical value for the third argument, it remain unevaluated and NDSolve cannot proceed its evaluation
The last example provided differs from yours since it does not involves derivatives, and in addition, the call is different in format (e.g., returning -x rather -x[t] and when you call it with x[t] it return the pattern -x[t])

One additional note - NDSolve evaluates its argument before it functions on them (since it has no HoldAll or HoldFirs or HoldRest attribute). This means that the rhsfunc is evaluated immediately with a symbol returning a non evaluated expression
As a rule of thumb, when using NDSolve prefer always Piecewise/ If/ Which. Piecewise was developed to function together with NDSolve and alike functions because of this behavior (starting in ver. 5.1). If you use patterns, use ?NumericQ as a test for the variables (NumberQ does not return True for expressions involving Pi or E etc., while NumericQ does).
This prevents the function from being evaluated for non numeric variables

I hope this helps

yehuda